# VSCODE Latex, security risk: running with elevated privileges

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

Environment:

- OS: Window 10,x64
- VSCode: 1.69.1
- Related VSCode Plugins installed: `LaTeX`,`LaTeX Workshop`,`LaTeX Utilities`,`LaTeX language support`
- Latex: `MiKTeX 21.12.10 Portable`
- The VSCode Configuration is below

```json
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex*2",
            "tools": ["pdflatex", "bibtex", "pdflatex","pdflatex"]
        },
        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "tools": ["xelatex"]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "tools": ["latexmk"]
        },
    ],
    
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": ["-synctex=1","-interaction=nonstopmode","-file-line-error","-pdf","-outdir=./output","%DOCFILE%"]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "command": "xelatex",
            "args": [ "-synctex=1","-interaction=nonstopmode","-file-line-error","-output-directory=./output","%DOCFILE%"]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",  
            "args": [ "-synctex=1","-interaction=nonstopmode","-file-line-error","-output-directory=./output","%DOCFILE%"]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "bibtex",
            "command": "bibtex",
            "args": [ "./output/%DOCFILE%"]  
        },
    ],
    
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",   
    "latex-workshop.latex.clean.fileTypes": [  
      "*.aux", 
      "*.bbl",
      "*.blg",
      "*.idx",
      "*.ind",
      "*.lof",
      "*.lot",
      "*.out",
      "*.toc",
      "*.acn",
      "*.acr",
      "*.alg",
      "*.glg",
      "*.glo",
      "*.gls",
      "*.ist",
      "*.fls",
      "*.log",
      "*.fdb_latexmk"
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run": "never",
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "first",
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.viewer.args": [
        "./output/%PDF%"
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "./output",
```

I use VSCode to write latex. And it occurs the errors below:

- `chktex: security risk: running with elevated privileges`
- `Cannot count words, code: 4294967295, texcount: security risk: running with elevated privileges`

**How to solve it?**

I have tried to run VSCode with administrator, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

Only the plugin `LaTeX Workshop` is needed. Other plugins(`LaTeX`,`LaTeX Utilities`,`LaTeX language support`) can be uninstalled.